# AWS Lambda upload file is broken

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have this code that works perfectly on local host (file uploads to aws s3 bucket properly) but when I upload the application to aws lambda, the file uploads to s3 as broken (shows up blank/weird byte characters). Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here? If I upload a txt file, things don't break so I am very confused.

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadNew",  method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA )
    public ResponseEntity uploadNew( @RequestParam("files") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {

        //put the object into the bucket
        ObjectMetadata data = new ObjectMetadata();
        data.setContentType(file.getContentType());
        data.setContentLength(file.getSize());
        BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials("xxxxx", "xxxxx");
        AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds)).build();
        PutObjectResult objectResult = s3client.putObject("xxxxx", file.getOriginalFilename(), file.getInputStream(), data);
```

Comment: How are you getting the file to the Lambda function? Is it posted from a form on a web page via API Gateway? By the way, there are two very questionable design choices here. 1. Running Java/Spring in Lambda and 2. POSTing files to a Lambda function so you can get them into S3 (consider just going direct from client to S3 via pre-signed URL vended by your server).

Comment: @jarmod if you can find me an implementation that works using a presigned url and an html post id believe you

Comment: form on api gateway -> s3

Comment: Prior experience (using NodeJS), trying to stream multipart data through API Gateway and Lambda to S3 just didn't work (although there are now parsers for Node that claim to have solved this issue). If you have the space you can construct the image in Lambda temp memory and then send it to S3, but that just smells. Completely agree with @jarmod, have an API/Lambda that generates a presigned URL then send the file directly to S3. and yes, this can be done with POST. Not sure what issues you're hitting with that, but feel free to raise another question.